# Task with one item only

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, having

My task table has an auto-increment ID field, to my taskitem table has a foreign key 'task_ID'. The taskitem element can have numerous task_IDs (a task can have numerous items).

I need to create a query that selects all task IDs from task WHERE the taskItem.task_ID is unique. ie: All tasks that have *one item only*.

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT t.ID 
FROM task AS t, taskitem AS ti 
WHERE ti.task_ID = t.ID AND ti.taskID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ti.taskID)
```

Comment: Okay... What did you already try? You know what you're after so i'm assuming you've already written the code and had issues?

Comment: This is what I tried and it returned everything. I know why but can't get my head around fixing it. SELECT t.ID FROM task AS t, taskitem AS ti WHERE ti.task_ID = t.ID AND ti.taskID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ti.taskID)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fetch all distinct taskIds which are unique from **taskitem** table:

```
SELECT ti.task_id 
FROM taskitem ti 
GROUP BY ti.task_id 
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1;
```

To fetch all unique task then use this query:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM task t 
INNER JOIN (SELECT ti.task_id 
            FROM taskitem ti 
            GROUP BY ti.task_id 
            HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
           ) AS ti ON t.id = ti.task_id;
```

Comment: Thank you. Apologies for the lazy question. Will accept in 5 mins.